# Get access the JavaScript loop value in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

#### Here is my code:

```
var marker,i,marker1,k;
for(i=0; i <20; i++)
{
//I want to assign this i variable value in php variable
function addMarker(latLng, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });
 //like as
    var conte='<?php $j="<script>document.write(i);</script>"; 
    ?>';
```

I want to use that value below here:

```
    var contentvalue= '<div style="color:   #008000;"><strong><b><?php echo  "$b[$j]" ?></b></strong></div>';
    
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentvalue,
           
        });
         marker.addListener('click', function() {
      
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
             return marker[i];
    }   
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. The PHP is run on the server and the JS is run on the client.

Comment: They're two different languages operating in two different environments. - You'll need to use AJAX to link client-side to server-side.

Comment: That won't work. PHP is parsed on the server and javascript is parsed in the client. That means that PHP gets parsed first and when it's done, the result is sent to the client.

Comment: Now how i can do this

Comment: Do you want a **PHP var in JS or a JS var in PHP**? @NaveedAbbas

Comment: How, depends on what you are going to do with the value. You can send the value to a separate PHP-script using Ajax, do stuff with it in PHP and then return the result to your Ajax script.

Comment: looking at this backwards ... create php array and either output that to javascript variable or make ajax request to get it

Comment: JS var in PHP @Mihailo

Comment: Could you please elaborate so that more people of knowledge could be engaged in your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are trying to do this backwards. You can use PHP to dynamically build a JavaScript block on the server side but, you cannot use PHP while JavaScript is executing. 
Since PHP is Server-side and JS is Client-side, you need to decide to go with one of the languages.

Also, you shouldn't be defining a function inside of your for loop. Just define the function outside and call it from within the for loop.

```
function addMarker(latLng, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });
    return marker;
}
function addInfoBox(contentString) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    return infowindow;
}
var i = 0
for(i=0; i < 20; i++)
{
    var contentString='<script>document.write('+i+');</script>'; 
    var marker = addMarker(latLng, map);
    var info = addInfoBox(contentString, marker);
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        info.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

This code is not at all perfect but, I think it gives a general idea of how you should start here. You'll have to clean it up and make sure it fits in with your application. I do not see a need for any PHP here as this is all client-side code and Google Maps API does not parse or execute any PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<script>    
    var phparr = <?php echo json_encode($phparr); ?>;

    for (i in phparr){

        alert("hey" + phparr[i]);

    }
</script>
```